# setTimeout() outputs a non expected number/timer

Tags: reactjs, settimeout

I'm trying to call the creator of action inside my `Action.js` to remove the alert after 3000ms with setTimeout(), and it outputs a number/timer `61` at the end of the message.

How can I remove this `61`.

Output:

```
Password too short (min 6 characs.)61
```

Code:

```
const Alert = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.alert && (
        <div className={`alert alert-${props.alert.type}`}>
          <i className="fas fa-info-circle"> {props.alert.msg}</i>
          {setTimeout(() => props.removeAlert(), 3000)}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should structure your code correctly like this:

```
const setAlert = props => 
{ 
  if(props.alert){
    setTimeout(() => props.removeAlert(), 3000)
    return (props.alert.msg); 
  }
};
```

Don't put everything under the return statement if it is just action and is not generating any value for you

I strongly recommend you to read the book ['Clean Code'](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) by Robert C. Martin

Answer (score 0):

I hope this can help you:

Try to separate concerns in your component, in this case the render and the set time out:

What version of react are you using? 
If you have higher that `16.8`
`Hooks` run after each render, including the first one so: you can try something like this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

useEffect(() => {
    // Run your setTimeout here!!!

  });

return (
  // Render your component
);
```

Or if you are using a lower version of react you can convert your component in a class component and instead of calling the setTimeout in the render method, use it in the `componentDidMount()`

```js
class Alert extends React.Component { 
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => this.props.removeAlert(), 3000)
  }

  render() {
    return (
     // Set your conditions &&
     // Render your message or component
   );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ruben. actually i just had to structure the code, i tried with what Bob said and it worked just fine :)